# Finding 2nd Vds value in a NMOS circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, nmos

[image]

I think for the first part of this problem I solved for Ra = 13kohm and Rb = 7kohm, but I'm not able to understand or see how to get the voltage at the point V1. Any idea on how to go about finding V1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both transistors conduct a current $$I_D=3.6mA$$.

Assume both of them operate in saturation (constant-current operation); use the relevant equation to find the overdrive voltage.

Then use $$V_{OV}=V_{GS}-V_{t}$$ to find the source voltage of transistor 2. The rest is easy.